# Where to ask about SNOM870 administrator access?

Tags: hardware, voip, firmware

I updated one of our SNOM870 VOIP handsets to FW 8.7.5.35 and now cannot access the phone's administrative interface.  The web access works and the phone finds the SIP proxy but many of the visible settings have changed such that the unit is no longer registered for the correct user. Further the communications SRTP settings of the unit are not compatible with the network.

The SNOM forums are closed to all but resellers.  I have asked on the FreePBX forums but have had no useful response. So I would like direction as where else I can seek assistance.

Comment: I had to deal with snom phones in a past life. Have you tried http://wiki.snom.com/Main_Page - just found http://wiki.snom.com/Settings/admin_mode_password

Comment: Been there several times.  The forums were closed several years ago and the information available is growing stale.  I ended up resetting the phone to get the default admin password reset to 0000 and proceeded from there.  I have been at this for the better part of two days and just decided to start from scratch.

Comment: Sometimes that's the correct course of action to take. The time taken to re-provision the phone after a factory reset is likely a fraction of the amount of effort to get back into it.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the phone to obtain the default administrative password of `0000`.